# Callback never called on Facebook Sample App

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have posted a bug on Facebook Developer :
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1598537583730278/

### What I've done :

Take HelloFacebookSample from facebook-android-sdk-4.4.0.zip and adapt it to make ot work for Android Studio.

build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.hellofacebook"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral() 
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.4.0'
}
```

I have added logs in HelloFacebookSampleActivity.java like so :

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2014-present, Facebook, Inc. All rights reserved.
 *
 * You are hereby granted a non-exclusive, worldwide, royalty-free license to use,
 * copy, modify, and distribute this software in source code or binary form for use
 * in connection with the web services and APIs provided by Facebook.
 *
 * As with any software that integrates with the Facebook platform, your use of
 * this software is subject to the Facebook Developer Principles and Policies
 * [http://developers.facebook.com/policy/]. This copyright notice shall be
 * included in all copies or substantial portions of the software.
 *
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
 * IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS
 * FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR
 * COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER
 * IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN
 * CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
 */

package com.example.hellofacebook;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.location.Location;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.*;
import com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger;
import com.facebook.login.LoginManager;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.ProfilePictureView;
import com.facebook.share.ShareApi;
import com.facebook.share.Sharer;
import com.facebook.share.model.SharePhoto;
import com.facebook.share.model.SharePhotoContent;
import com.facebook.share.model.ShareLinkContent;
import com.facebook.share.widget.ShareDialog;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class HelloFacebookSampleActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private static final String PERMISSION = "publish_actions";
    private static final Location SEATTLE_LOCATION = new Location("") {
        {
            setLatitude(47.6097);
            setLongitude(-122.3331);
        }
    };

    private final String PENDING_ACTION_BUNDLE_KEY =
            "com.example.hellofacebook:PendingAction";

    private Button postStatusUpdateButton;
    private Button postPhotoButton;
    private ProfilePictureView profilePictureView;
    private TextView greeting;
    private PendingAction pendingAction = PendingAction.NONE;
    private boolean canPresentShareDialog;
    private boolean canPresentShareDialogWithPhotos;
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private ProfileTracker profileTracker;
    private ShareDialog shareDialog;
    private FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result> shareCallback = new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d("HelloFacebook", "Canceled");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Log.d("HelloFacebook", String.format("Error: %s", error.toString()));
            String title = getString(R.string.error);
            String alertMessage = error.getMessage();
            showResult(title, alertMessage);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
            Log.d("HelloFacebook", "Success!");
            if (result.getPostId() != null) {
                String title = getString(R.string.success);
                String id = result.getPostId();
                String alertMessage = getString(R.string.successfully_posted_post, id);
                showResult(title, alertMessage);
            }
        }

        private void showResult(String title, String alertMessage) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(HelloFacebookSampleActivity.this)
                    .setTitle(title)
                    .setMessage(alertMessage)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null)
                    .show();
        }
    };

    private enum PendingAction {
        NONE,
        POST_PHOTO,
        POST_STATUS_UPDATE
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        Log.e("FACEBOOK SAMPLE", "ON CREATE");

        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        Log.e("FACEBOOK SAMPLE", "ON SUCCESS");
                        handlePendingAction();
                        updateUI();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        Log.e("FACEBOOK SAMPLE", "ON CANCEL");
                        if (pendingAction != PendingAction.NONE) {
                            showAlert();
                            pendingAction = PendingAction.NONE;
                        }
                        updateUI();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                        Log.e("FACEBOOK SAMPLE", "ON ERROR");
                        if (pendingAction != PendingAction.NONE
                                && exception instanceof FacebookAuthorizationException) {
                            showAlert();
                            pendingAction = PendingAction.NONE;
                        }
                        updateUI();
                    }

                    private void showAlert() {
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(HelloFacebookSampleActivity.this)
                                .setTitle(R.string.cancelled)
                                .setMessage(R.string.permission_not_granted)
                                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

        shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
        shareDialog.registerCallback(
                callbackManager,
                shareCallback);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            String name = savedInstanceState.getString(PENDING_ACTION_BUNDLE_KEY);
            pendingAction = PendingAction.valueOf(name);
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile currentProfile) {
                updateUI();
                // It's possible that we were waiting for Profile to be populated in order to
                // post a status update.
                handlePendingAction();
            }
        };

        profilePictureView = (ProfilePictureView) findViewById(R.id.profilePicture);
        greeting = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.greeting);

        postStatusUpdateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.postStatusUpdateButton);
        postStatusUpdateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onClickPostStatusUpdate();
            }
        });

        postPhotoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.postPhotoButton);
        postPhotoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onClickPostPhoto();
            }
        });

        // Can we present the share dialog for regular links?
        canPresentShareDialog = ShareDialog.canShow(
                ShareLinkContent.class);

        // Can we present the share dialog for photos?
        canPresentShareDialogWithPhotos = ShareDialog.canShow(
                SharePhotoContent.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Call the 'activateApp' method to log an app event for use in analytics and advertising
        // reporting.  Do so in the onResume methods of the primary Activities that an app may be
        // launched into.
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);

        updateUI();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putString(PENDING_ACTION_BUNDLE_KEY, pendingAction.name());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        // Call the 'deactivateApp' method to log an app event for use in analytics and advertising
        // reporting.  Do so in the onPause methods of the primary Activities that an app may be
        // launched into.
        AppEventsLogger.deactivateApp(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        profileTracker.stopTracking();
    }

    private void updateUI() {
        boolean enableButtons = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null;

        postStatusUpdateButton.setEnabled(enableButtons || canPresentShareDialog);
        postPhotoButton.setEnabled(enableButtons || canPresentShareDialogWithPhotos);

        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        if (enableButtons && profile != null) {
            profilePictureView.setProfileId(profile.getId());
            greeting.setText(getString(R.string.hello_user, profile.getFirstName()));
        } else {
            profilePictureView.setProfileId(null);
            greeting.setText(null);
        }
    }

    private void handlePendingAction() {
        PendingAction previouslyPendingAction = pendingAction;
        // These actions may re-set pendingAction if they are still pending, but we assume they
        // will succeed.
        pendingAction = PendingAction.NONE;

        switch (previouslyPendingAction) {
            case NONE:
                break;
            case POST_PHOTO:
                postPhoto();
                break;
            case POST_STATUS_UPDATE:
                postStatusUpdate();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void onClickPostStatusUpdate() {
        performPublish(PendingAction.POST_STATUS_UPDATE, canPresentShareDialog);
    }

    private void postStatusUpdate() {
        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setContentTitle("Hello Facebook")
                .setContentDescription(
                        "The 'Hello Facebook' sample  showcases simple Facebook integration")
                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://developers.facebook.com/docs/android"))
                .build();
        if (canPresentShareDialog) {
            shareDialog.show(linkContent);
        } else if (profile != null && hasPublishPermission()) {
            ShareApi.share(linkContent, shareCallback);
        } else {
            pendingAction = PendingAction.POST_STATUS_UPDATE;
        }
    }

    private void onClickPostPhoto() {
        performPublish(PendingAction.POST_PHOTO, canPresentShareDialogWithPhotos);
    }

    private void postPhoto() {
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
        SharePhoto sharePhoto = new SharePhoto.Builder().setBitmap(image).build();
        ArrayList<SharePhoto> photos = new ArrayList<>();
        photos.add(sharePhoto);

        SharePhotoContent sharePhotoContent =
                new SharePhotoContent.Builder().setPhotos(photos).build();
        if (canPresentShareDialogWithPhotos) {
            shareDialog.show(sharePhotoContent);
        } else if (hasPublishPermission()) {
            ShareApi.share(sharePhotoContent, shareCallback);
        } else {
            pendingAction = PendingAction.POST_PHOTO;
            // We need to get new permissions, then complete the action when we get called back.
            LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(
                    this,
                    Arrays.asList(PERMISSION));
        }
    }

    private boolean hasPublishPermission() {
        AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
        return accessToken != null && accessToken.getPermissions().contains("publish_actions");
    }

    private void performPublish(PendingAction action, boolean allowNoToken) {
        AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
        if (accessToken != null || allowNoToken) {
            pendingAction = action;
            handlePendingAction();
        }
    }
}
```

### The problem :

Upon connection, the facebook activity displays with no error but when I click on the cancel or on the ok button, it goes back on HelloFacebookSampleActivity but it fires the onCreate() function.
As described in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html, an Activity can be stopped and killed at any moment even if it is still in the activity stack and in this case it fires onCreate() when the app goes back on it.
As a result the callback is reinitialized and it's not possible to get the response from the authentication.
This bug happens with the LG G2 mini but not with the Samsung Galaxy s4.
The app seems to work fine otherwise.

I have had this problem with my current app even by doing step by step the facebook android sdk tutorial and I have the same problem with the official sample app.

If I go to the phone menu when in the HelloFacebookSampleActivity and then go back to the app, onCreate() is not necessarily fired, it does sometimes if I wait long enough before reopening the app.

I hope I'm doing something wrong.

Anyway thank you in advance for any help given.

Android Studio Version : 1.2.2

Test telephones : LG G2 mini with Android 5.0.2, Samsung Galaxy S4 with Android 5.0.1

SDK version: 4.4.0

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing same issue, I have found the solution by overriding `onActivityResult` method.

After putting this method in my activity class, then all callback will work

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Comment: It wasn't enough for me and as you can see with the facebook bug link, it was a problem with the facebook sdk and will be fixed with the next release

Comment: This was exactly the fix I needed. Can anyone explain why this is necessary to get the basic [fb-login example](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android) going?